# How can I override a default of rootpw in sudoers

Tags: sudo, sudoers

I have a `sudoers` file with *many* entries.

At the top is a Defaults setting:

```
# default sudo password is the ROOT password (not the invoking user's password)
Defaults rootpw
```

However there is one particular command I want to let users run as root so long as they enter their *own* password.

How can I specify a particular command requires the invoking user's password - thereby overriding the "Defaults" set?

e.g. how to modify the below command to require the invoking user's password (*not* the root password):

```
markus ALL = PASSWD: /usr/sbin/tcpdump -p -i eth2 host 192.168.14.15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
Defaults!/usr/sbin/tcpdump !rootpw
```

to disable `rootpw` for a single command. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80159/4241) and/or `man 5 sudoers` for more information.

Alternatively, `NOPASSWD` option disables password prompt altogether, e.g

```
markus ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/tcpdump -p -i eth2 host 192.168.14.15
```

finally, you can disable `rootpw` from a single user with

```
Defaults:markus !rootpw
```

---

If you want to override `rootpw` for a specific user and specific command, at least following workaround can be used: create wrapper script, e.g `/usr/local/bin/special_tcpdump.sh`

```
 #!/bin/sh
 /usr/sbin/tcpdump $*
```

Then, configure `sudoers`:

```
 Defaults!/usr/local/bin/special_tcpdump.sh !rootpw
 markus ALL = PASSWD: /usr/local/bin/special_tcpdump.sh -p -i eth2 host 192.168.14.15
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy answer. In particular I want to allow /bin/bash for particular users on particular users... so I wonder if I can have a Defaults for combination, e.g. `Defaults:PARTICULAR_USERS@PARTICULAR_HOSTS!/bin/bash !rootpw`

Comment: OR if I cannot combine `Defaults` types on a single line (tried it and didn't parse) can I put a `Defaults !rootpw` on the line above my specific command and a `Defaults rootpw` below the specific command?

Comment: You certainly can't put multiple `Defaults` lines all over the file - those are applied globally, not only after the fact. For command&user pairs, I updated the answer.